# How to catch errors in all meteor subscriptions with iron-router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, subscriptions

I've got a typical iron-router project with subscriptions for each route. I'd like to be able to catch any subscription errors and notify the user.

Is there any way to do this globally? Something like:

```
Router.onSubscriptionError(function (error) {alert(error);});
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm using this workaround:

Define a helper method on my notifications object:

`Notify.subscribe = {
    onError: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Notify.error("Couldn't get data: ", error + '');
    }
};`

Pass that helper to all subscriptions:

```
Meteor.subscribe('current_user_data', Notify.subscribe)
```